# Do I really need to send my US tax return via certified mail?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I had always sent my returns in certified mail until this year when a state return said sending certified would actually delay the process. Is there a best way to send returns for federal and states in general that do not explicitly say the best way to mail on their website?

Edit: An example of a state saying it can actually delay the process:
[Maryland](http://individuals.marylandtaxes.com/filinginfo/mailing.asp), [Georgia](https://etax.dor.ga.gov/inctax/webfaq/indv_helpful_hints.pdf)

Comment: it delays the process because of the more rigorous manual processing in the mailing room. That's because it's certified. What's not certified - can be lost with no damages to the state, so they don't have to be so strict about it. But, then again - that's exactly what you want to avoid.

Comment: Does the irs send out amended returns by certified mail?

Comment: @ryann that's not related to this question and should be a new question (unless it's a dupe, but I don't easily find any such). But the IRS doesn't send out any returns, amended or not (except when you request and pay for a copy of a return you previously filed, perhaps lost in a flood). They do send *notices* when they aren't happy with your return (or lack thereof) and especially when they want more money, and those (often?) are sent certified mail; certainly several I have received were (and I had to sign for them) although I believe some "minor" ones aren't.

Answer (score 13):

No.

If you send them well ahead of time, then you can be sure they arrived by having a copy of the cashed check you sent to the IRS, or if a refund was due - receiving the refund.

But if you're sending close to the deadline (March and later) - you might not receive the refund check (or your check might not be cashed) before the Tax Day, and you won't have any proof that you sent it. So, to avoid late fees and penalties, if you send 1-1.5 months before the due date or later - send certified.

It is a good practice, however, to send it certified always. You never know what might happen, and it doesn't cost that much more. The burden of proof that you filed your taxes, and did it on time, is on you.

The best way, in my opinion, is e-filing.

Comment: And yet, I continued to get updated 1099 and other forms well into March this year. You are rather trusting to file a return so early.

Comment: @Joe, you're right, I just described a situation when sending by regular mail would still be considered "safe" in my opinion. Since most people do send out the taxes in April, they should use certified mail (or, as I did, e-file).

Answer (score 6):

If you're submitting your tax return at or near the deadline, you can use [IRS-specified private delivery services](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p80/ar01.html#en_US_2011_publink1000233902) to meet the timely filing requirement. Your state's requirements may vary, so check with your tax or revenue department's website.

Some people feel that using USPS Certified or Registered mail gives you some additional legal protections, as US Code explicitly states that the receipt from such a service is prima facie evidence of filing. (Although it may delay processing, particularly with registered mail, which requires a written audit trail for every USPS employee who has custody of the letter)

I'd suggest that USPS Certified Mail is the cheapest way to submit your returns if you require documentation for a last-minute filing. If you care about processing time, file early via first class mail or e-file.